# Why did my reputation go up?

Tags: support, reputation, recent-activity

Is there a way to tell why my reputation has changed?  Overnight I gained reputation, and I'm wondering how I could find out which answers and questions got down and upvoted.

Comment: @Gnome: Pretty silly to ask a question, answer it yourself, find a question that's older and just like, and call it a duplicate. If anything, *yours* is the duplicate.

Comment: @gman: Answering your own FAQ questions is *recommended* on the [FAQ index](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/).  Indicating duplicates of FAQs is also recommended.  I realize this question is older, but I neither knew about it at the time I answered the other nor is this one in the recommended form for FAQs.  If I hadn't been editing & retagging ~100 questions tonight, I wouldn't have even found this one.  Exactly what problem do you see?

Comment: @Gnome: I know answering your own question is recommended, I know indicating duplicates is also recommended, and I know this isn't in FAQ form. But you could edit *this* question to make it so. I'm just pointing out it's a bit unorthodox to claim a question is a duplicate (which means it predicted the future, very cool), when it's "not". I'm not saying your newer QA is worse; in fact I think it's much better. But I think a better comment would have just been "FAQ'd: [link]", whereas the stigma around "Duplicate:" is a bit worse.

Comment: @gman: Perhaps I just didn't see the same stigma you did there (but did see it in the "pretty silly" comment), but I am fine changing to "FAQ'd". :)  Even if I had seen this question first (I didn't, I added the FAQ after not finding an FAQ for [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45700/augment-envelope-with-recent-or-activity-or-responses-link/45710#45710)), I also think editing this question would've been a worse result than the other, because editing this and deleting the other did flash briefly through my mind earlier.

Comment: FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45708/how-do-i-view-my-recent-replies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to your profile and see the Reputations Tab

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9516?sort=reputationhistory#sort-top

And to see the latest changes select the rightmost area by clicking and dragging the rightmost chart area.
Then only the latest answers of yours will be filtered!

Comment: Sadly, as much as I love that they did this, it still doesn't REALLY answer the question of what exactly changed since last night, only what has changed ever.

Comment: I agree. It would be nice to be able to see the individual votes ordered chronologically.

Comment: The graph is selectable. To see the changes for a time period, just select a portion of the graph.

Comment: It doesn't show the latest items when I select only that region. If I select the last full day, then I'm still missing events that might only have taken place recently

Comment: @workmad3: That's cool.  I had no idea you could select a subset of the graph.  They should put a tooltip on, or a note above/below, the graph.

Answer (score 9):

We all realized how great a person you are. We had a vote and everything. Do you want a slice of the cake we bought you?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question this morining.  Here's what I found...

Click on your name at the top of the webpage to view your profile.  On your profile page there is a tabbed interface.  One tab is 'reputation' where it lists all the questions where you either gained or lost reputation.

Comment: And you see that graph on the reputation tab?  Drag a time range, and you can see how many votes you got and on what in that time period.

Answer (score 5):

I use the Unofficial Stackoverflow Update script

http://modos.org/sof/?u=UserNumberHere

It'll show you which questions have been voted up or down since the last time you viewed the page.

I found out about this page from the question [track-your-reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553/track-your-reputation).

---

See the *[What 3rd Party Tools Exist for StackOverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248296/what-third-party-tools-exist-to-use-with-stackoverflow)* answer to the [Unofficial FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq) for more fun stuff..

Comment: modos.org/sof/ is 404.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with this -- if you get reputation from a question that's since been closed, you'll still have those points, but they won't show up in your Reputation graph. There doesn't seen to be any way to find out where they came from.

Comment: I assumed that was divine intervention.